# Как переименовать файл в cLion 2021(текстовый редактор)

Tags: clion

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Когда я меняю имя файла вручную,то он перестает работать.Вы знаете,как грамотно поменять имя файла или как его изначально поставить?

Comment: Что значит перестает работать? IDE его перестает видеть? или сборка не проходит? В последнем случае нужно в make-файл внести новое имя файла.

Comment: Сейчас покажу,что пишет

Comment: Когда я поменял имя файла,появилась желтая надпись и не работает

Comment: потому что CLion хоть и выглядит как текстовый редактор, но им плохо работает. У CLion есть файл проекта и там файлы числятся по имени. Когда Вы переименовываете файл известным Вам способом, то IDE не может об этом догадаться. Думаю, если файл переименовать в дереве проекта, то оно сможет (но у меня нет этой среды разработки, так что не могу не подтвердить, не опровергнуть)

Comment: Выбрать файл, нажать F2, или пкм по файлу, рефакторинг, переименовать.